# How to add comment with JIRA REST Api to issue Subversion tab

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a problem with jira post adding. I'want my added comments to be in Subversion or Commits tab, but I've only managed to put in the comments section.

If it is not possible I would like to ask how to edit the html of the certain comment

Answer (score 0):

The commits tab is getting its data from Subversion or Git, so you can't just add comments there

Answer (score 0):

From the JIRA REST API documentation:

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-addWorklog

you should be able to add entries to the "work log".

Basically (Perl-ish pseudo code):

$content = q/{
    "comment": "I did some work here.",
    "visibility": {
        "type": "group",
        "value": "jira-developers"
    },
    "started": "2016-09-28T15:37:31.449+0000",
    "timeSpentSeconds": 12000
}
/;

$resp = httprequest(HTTP_POST, "/rest/api/2/issue/$issueID/worklog", $content);

(updated to add sample pseudo code)